# Split dataframe based on multiple columns pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of Dataframe, I would split into multiple dataframes with unique value in multiple columns.
DF:

```
    a       b       c   d
0   red     green   1   2
1   brown   red     4   5
2   black   grey    0   0
3   red     blue    6   1
4   green   blue    0   3
5   black   brown   2   8
6   red     grey    4   6
```

I am able do it based on a single column with this code `df_list = [d for _, d in df.groupby(['a'])]`
I am able to do the operations that I want with:

```
for df in df_list:
    df["e"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name+1:,"c"].mean(),axis=1)
```

Output

```
df_list
[       a      b  c  d    e
 2  black   grey  0  0  2.0
 5  black  brown  2  8  NaN,
        a      b  c  d    e
 1  brown    red  4  5  NaN,
        a      b  c  d    e
 4  green   blue  0  3  NaN,
       a       b  c  d    e
 0    red  green  1  2  5.0
 3    red   blue  6  1  4.0
 6    red   grey  4  6  NaN]
```

But how to do it with multiple columns?

Expected Result for "red" value:

```
    a       b       c   d   e
0   red     green   1   2   5.0
1   brown   red     4   5   5.0
2   red     blue    6   1   4.0
3   red     grey    4   6   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the unique values of both the `a` and `b` columns and use each one as a filter. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["red", "green", 1, 2],
        ["brown", "red", 4, 5],
        ["black", "grey", 0, 0],
        ["red", "blue", 6, 1],
        ["green", "blue", 0, 3],
        ["black", "brown", 2, 8],
        ["red", "grey", 4, 6],
    ],
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
)

colors = pd.unique(df[['a', 'b']].values.ravel('K'))

>>> colors
    array(['red', 'brown', 'black', 'green', 'grey', 'blue'], dtype=object)
```

Iterate over each color and perform your operation on the resulting `current_df` after filtering.

```
df_list = []
for color in colors:
    current_df = df[(df.a == color) | (df.b == color)].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
    current_df["e"] = current_df.apply(
        lambda x: (
            current_df[(current_df.a == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "c"].sum()
            + current_df[(current_df.b == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "d"].sum()
        )
        / (current_df.shape[0] - x.name - 1),
        axis=1
    )
    df_list.append(current_df)
```

`(current_df.shape[0] - x.name - 1)` becomes the number of values that were added, because `x.name` is the row number and `current_df.shape[0]` is the total number of rows of the current filtered `df`. This is equivalent to:

```
df_list = []
for color in colors:
    current_df = df[(df.a == color) | (df.b == color)].copy()
    current_df["e"] = current_df.apply(
        lambda x: (
            current_df[(current_df.a == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "c"].sum()
            + current_df[(current_df.b == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "d"].sum()
        )
        / (
            current_df[(current_df.a == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "c"].size
            + current_df[(current_df.b == color)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "d"].size
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
    df_list.append(current_df)
```

Result for red:

```
>>> df_list[0]
           a      b  c  d    e
    0    red  green  1  2  5.0
    1  brown    red  4  5  5.0
    3    red   blue  6  1  4.0
    6    red   grey  4  6  NaN
```

Comment: Great! But there is an issue, it calculates values in column "c" but there is a value for "red" in column "d", so there result for the first row should be 5+4+6 instead of 4+6+4

Comment: Check it out now, @CharlesAlakis

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!